# Revisiting some nodes in a recursive function (DFS) over a tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

I traverse the nodes of a tree in depth-first manner. Suppose the tree is as follows:
[image]

Now, suppose that I am in node `E` and for some condition I want to back to the node `C` and continue from there. Then previous traversing should be canceled and node `C`, `D`, `E` should be evaluated again. Node `F` and `G` shouldn't be traversed twice as the previous recursive navigation has been cancelled!

```
Usual navigation : A B C D E F G
The desire navigation : A B C D E C D E F G
```

The general code of depth-first traversing is as follows:

```
void DFS(node x)
{
    z = evaluate(x);
    // if (z != null) DFS(z) 
    // Z could be a node which has been already traversed, 
    // let's suppose it's an ancestor of x

    foreach (node y in c.children)
    {
        DFS(y);
    }
}
```

Please help me how can I have such navigation in the tree?

Comment: Can you just explain a little more its not clear from the statement. You are doing a DFS and you have visited some nodes now at some node you evaluate something and for that u want to re-evaluate the nodes in the previous level ?

Comment: @Anup Yes I should cancel the recursion and back to a node and continue traversing from there

Comment: ok that means if I have evaluated something in E then I have to redo C,D,E, F and for A it will continue as it was?

Comment: Is `z` always an ancestor of `x` (as it would be for, e.g., cycle cancelling)?

Comment: @Ahmad Clear it man if you hit something at E then as you have not evaluated F and G so you are not going to evaluate them and you will evaluate all the previous nodes but only on the current level as you have not mentioned re evaluation of B or A.? is that it?

Comment: @Anup Yes redo C, D, E   and continue with F and G

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes I guess it is always an ancestor, we can suppose that

Comment: @DavidEisenstat it says DFS on a tree that cancels the Cycle thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how far back up the tree you want to go, something like this should work.

The DFS function returns the number of levels to retry:

- 0 to carry on as normal
- 1 to retry the same node
- 2 to retry the parent...

Code:

```
int DFS(node x)
{
    if (some condition)
    {
        // return the number of parent levels you want to back up
        return 2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x.children.size; ++i)
    {
        int redo = DFS(x.children[i]);

        if (redo == 1) {
            // redo == 1 means retry the current node
            --i;
        }
        if (redo > 1) {
        {
            // redo > 1 means retry an ancestor node
            return redo - 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously you have to be careful with your condition, or you'll end up in an infinite loop.

With the base code as above, the following condition will return `A B C D E C D E F G`

```
boolean retryE = true;

int DFS(node x)
{
    if (x.value == "E" && retryE)
    {
        retryE = false;
        return 2;
    }

    // remaining code as above
}
```

**Update**

Looking again, if your evaluate function returns an ancestor node not a number of levels, this may be closer to what you originally wanted... Will fail if the node returned is not an ancestor of the current child...

```
// returns null to continue DFS, or a node value to repeat from that node
Node DFS(Node x)
{
    Node z = evaluate(x)

    if (z != null)
    {
        return z;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x.children.size; ++i)
    {
        Node child = x.children[i];
        Node result = DFS(child);

        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result == child)
            {
                // current child is the one to retry so just
                // decrement the counter to retry it
                --i;
            } else {
                // retry a node but not this child so return it up the stack
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Update 2**

Using the same DFS function, consider this evaluate function, which returns C for the first occurence of both E and F

```
boolean retryE = true;
boolean retryF = true;

evaluate(Node x)
{
    if (x.value == "E" && retryE)
    {
        retryE = false;
        return C;
    }
    if (x.value == "F" && retryF)
    {
        retryF = false;
        return C;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will work correctly using the `--i` decrement method (returning `A B C D E - C D E F - C D E F G`), but not if calling `DFS(child)` directly, unless the result of the second call is processed somehow.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems promising, I am testing it

Comment: To retry a child, can't I just call `DFS(child)` instead of `--i`?

Comment: @Ahmad if you call DFS(child) it will process all children but will resume form where it left off afterwards. So in your example above, you will get A B C D E - C D E F - F G, so you get an extra F. The essence of both approaches above is that the recursion backtracks up the stack to the node to repeat, and then restarts from that point.

Comment: I see your point about backtracking up, just I mean where you used `if (result == child)` you decremented `i` and this calls the `DFS(child)` in the next loop, but you may directly call `DFS(child)`.

Comment: @Ahmad You could call DFS(child) directly, but I don't think it would work in all cases, unless you also processed the result of that second call somehow. Have a look at the code in Update 2 above where both node E and node F cause the recursion to backtrack. This works with the --i backtracking, but if calling DFS(child) directly you'd still have to consider the result of that second call somewhere... you probably could still do it this way, but would require a bit more thought.

Comment: How about poping from StackA and after evaluation push ti to stackB, then when we need to back to X, pop from stackB until X, push to stackA, and then continue? I say this in the cases any visited node can be redone and not only ancestors?

Comment: @Ahmad If its not an ancestor then it gets a lot more complicated, and would need a different approach. For example, if `evaluate(E) -> B`, then you would presumably want `A B C D E B C D E F G`, but I can't see any easy way to do this using just a DFS search. Depending on the size, I'd probably pre-process the entire tree into a list first (`A B C D E F G`), then process that list, using the evaluate function to jump forward / backward in the list as necessary.

Comment: Thank you, forget about that, but what about using just one "retry" variable? it can be set to `false` before the loop, and set to `true` before `--i`, actually when I back to `C`, I don't want to reevaluate the `C` but its children.

Comment: @Ahmad Sorry, I'm not sure what the exact question is now. Are you saying that if `evaluate(E) -> C` then the required output is `A B C D E D E F G` (which is different to what you have in the original question where C occurs twice)? If so, then yes you probably could add a flag to skip the parent when retrying it, but for anything more complicated I'd probably change the approach entirely, as per the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, its better we ignore the `C`, but my offer also doesn't work.We ignore it or not, I just like to use one flag! is it possible? the flag as I noticed is mainly used to not back again to `C` when the `E` is being reevaluated. Otherwise it would raise the same condition and falls into an infinite loop. I am working on it and will say to you, but if had any comment it is welcomed.

Comment: No matter, thank you for all the helps, I use a flag for each element.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to outline a pseudocode using a global variable `cancel`.

```
boolean cancel = false;

void DFS(node x, parent p)
{
    if(!cancel) {
        foreach (node y in x.children) {
            DFS(y, x);
        }
    } else {
      cancel = false;
      DFS(p, findParent(p));
    }
}
```

However, there is a problem with this approach. Once the traversal has started in the foreach section, each subsequent call to the DFS method within the loop will invoke the DFS from parent node. To address this concern, I would recommend you to simulate the depth first traversal by using your own stack rather than taking the recursive approach. That way, when `cancel` becomes `true`, you can clear the stack and ensure that DFS call from the parent happens only once. Hope this helps!

Something among the following lines should work:

```
boolean cancel = false;
Stack<Node> s;

void DFSIterative(Node x, Node p) {
    if(cancel) {
        resetDFS(p);
    } else {
        s.push(x);
        while(!s.isEmpty()) {
            x = s.pop();
            p = findParent(x);
            if(cancel) resetDFS;
            else {
                foreach(node y in x.children) {
                    s.push(y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void resetDFS(Node p) {
    s.clear();
    cancel = false;
    DFSIterative(p, findParent(p));
}
```

I leave the implementation of findParent() helper method to you. Please note that you will also need to take care of marking the nodes as visited and then unmarking relevant nodes as unvisited when you cancel DFS.

Comment: What is the role of `p` here?

Comment: it denotes the ancestor of current node being traversed.

Comment: Could you use two stacks to move back and forth in nodes?

Answer (score 0):

See here I can see that u have used a void DFS that is your function is not returning anything so you can use that value to check if something is need to be reevaluated.

Like this

```
int DFS(node x)
{
    int ret=0;
    z = evaluate(x);
    // if (z != null) DFS(z) Z could be a node which has been already traversed 
    foreach (node y in c.children)
    {
        ret=DFS(y);
        if(ret==1)
          break;
    }
    if(ret==1)
       DFS(x);

    if(z==(want to reevaluate))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Now by this you can simply return to the parent 1 if you want it to redo the DFS on all its children and you can simply return 0 if you want it to simply continue.
If any of the children of A returned 1 in that case All the children and that node will be reevaluated and the nodes above it will continue in the same way as they were.

So by you image.If E returns 1 then all of the nodes C,D,E will be reevaluated. If you have return value fixed to return distance or something then this could be done using a variable also, you just need to send its address to all the children and watch for its value.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think the other answer is more general. you suppose z is parent, while it can be any ancestor